# How to add Paypal Express Checkout button on a CMS page?

Tags: magento-1.8, paypal, paypal-express

I want to add a `Paypal Express Checkout` button on a CMS page to capture specific payment. Please help me. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Can you explain a bit what are you trying to achieve? I mean the actual use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a phtml file, and then call your phtml file via `CMS Pages`:

```
{{block type="core/template" template="page/page.phtml"}}
```

Use your `paypal express checkout` code in that file.

The button on cart page links to the url `"STORE.DOMAIN/paypal/express/start/`" which is ultimately handled by `startAction()` method in

> app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Controller/Express/Abstract.php

Comment: Can you tell me where can i find my Paypal Express Checkout code?

Comment: This link can help you, i also update my answer for the path to ecc file:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855441/magento-working-of-paypal-express-checkout

Comment: I am able to display the button on the CMS page but how can i make it checkout with the desired amount i want to be captured? And also i'm getting this error: "Unable to communicate with the PayPal gateway."

Answer (score 1):

If you are a programmer, you have to do custom work or hire a developer. Follow the helping [Guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/gs_expresscheckout/) provided by Paypal. They have provided SDK's and some samples as well. you can make it work accordingly.